# Google Map freezes after repainting MarkerClusterPlus

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a map with a few MarkerWithLabel objects on it (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/). The labels, in this case, are integers.

I also have a MarkerClustererPlus (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.1.2/) which also works fine.

However, I want to change the text on Clusters to show the sum of those integers on labels for every MarkerWithLabel inside a Cluster.

I did that by binding this function to the end of clustering:

```
function calculateClusterLabels() {
    $.each(markerCluster.clusters_, function(i, cluster){
        var sum = 0;
        var cluster_markers = cluster.getMarkers();
        $.each(cluster_markers, function(j, marker) {
            sum += marker.labelContent;
        });
        cluster.clusterIcon_.sums_['text'] = sum;
        cluster.updateIcon(); // also tried cluster.repaint();
    });
}
```

And that works - at least for the Cluster text. But now we are getting to the real problem: it freezes the whole Map. Raven.js catches this: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. But nothing clearer than this.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Some more code. Data is fetched with ajax and then the markers are set in a loop:

```
$.each(us_data, function(k, v) {
    var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(us_data[k]['lat'], us_data[k]['lon']);
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: markerPosition,
        draggable: false,
        map: map,
        labelContent: us_data[k]['count'],
        labelAnchor: anchor,
        labelClass: "marker-with-label"
    });

markers.push(marker);
});
```

And then I make the Clusters and bind the event:

```
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/images/m'});
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusteringend', function() {
    calculateClusterLabels();
});
```

This all happens inside the .done() of ajax, but markerCluster and markers are visible outside.

Comment: We need more code to answer your question. Look into `getTotalMarkers` and `getMarkers` in each cluster.

Comment: I've added some more code. I do use the getMarkers method

Comment: Please check this article: http://www.toptal.com/javascript/10-most-common-javascript-mistakes. Its a comprehensive guide to common javascript mistakes which result into the said error.
I'm somewhat convinced that #6 is the reason that you are getting it.
Hope it helps!

Comment: @KayAnn thanks, but that wasn't the problem. I will update my question with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer myself: well, it was fairly simple after all:

```
function calculateClusterLabels() {
    $.each(markerCluster.clusters_, function(i, cluster){
        var sum = 0;
        var cluster_markers = cluster.getMarkers();
        $.each(cluster_markers, function(j, marker) {
            sum += marker.labelContent;
        });
        if (cluster.clusterIcon_.sums_ != null) {
            cluster.clusterIcon_.sums_['text'] = sum;
        }
    });
}
```

What I did - I added a simple if statement to check whether the .sums_ object is not null (because it wasn't null only on the visible clusters that had markers inside) and I omitted the .updateIcon call and everything works perfectly, no errors.

An even better solution, for my case, was to simply change the markerclusterer.js source file:

```
MarkerClusterer.CALCULATOR = function (markers, numStyles) {
  var index = 0;
  var title = "";
  var count = 0;
  if (typeof markers[0].labelContent != 'undefined') {
      var sum = 0;
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
          if (!isNaN(markers[i].labelContent) {
              sum += markers[i].labelContent;
          } else {
              // whatever we need, perhaps we want to calculate it differently
          }
      }
      count = sum.toString();
  } else {
      count = markers.length.toString();
  }

  var dv = count;
  while (dv !== 0) {
    dv = parseInt(dv / 10, 10);
    index++;
  }

  index = Math.min(index, numStyles);
  return {
    text: count,
    index: index,
    title: title
  };
};
```

This was even better because it updated Cluster styles, as well and it works both with regular Marker and MarkerWithLabel objects.